# vim:what's the difference between buffers and args

Tags: vim, arguments, buffer, difference

I'm using vim,when I see the :args command ，I don't know the difference between args and buffers.
in vim,I know buffers is important, so I thought :arg* is not important,maybe it's a "legacy command", but when I play the *vim genius* game ,I see arg*

someone have any idea?

Answer (score 11):

**What is a Vim buffer?**

A buffer is a file loaded into memory for editing. All opened files are associated with a buffer.

**How do I identify a buffer?**

Vim buffers are identified using a name and a number. 
The name of the buffer is the name of the file associated with that buffer. 
The buffer number is a unique sequential number assigned by Vim. 
This buffer number will not change in a single Vim session

The argument list is a subset of the buffer list. If you've just launched Vim, then the buffer list will be relatively empty.

Buffer List ==> files in vim buffers

Args List ==> files open at the dos/linux command line or open from the vim command line using :args (example open all c files in current directory :args *.c)

Here is a more detailed description and useful tips [Buffer List v Argument List](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/u3nv6/buffer_list_vs_arguments_list)